# rlang: Creating empty lists from variable character input

Tags: r, rlang, tidyeval

To specify arguments in function created in the `args`-argument of `rlang::new_function`, I am looking fora way to create *empty* lists. These could then be fed into `new_function` and return functions with predefined arguments.

```r
library(rlang)
create_empty_list <- function(arg_names_chr) {
  # input lenght should be variable, so probably !!! should be used
}

create_empty_list(arg_names_chr = c("arg1", "arg2"))
#> NULL

# desired output
args_specified <- exprs(arg1=, arg2=)
args_specified
#> $arg1
#> 
#> 
#> $arg2

# use with new_function()
new_function(
  args_specified,
  expr(print("hello world")),
  caller_env()
)
#> function (arg1, arg2) 
#> print("hello world")
```

What I have tried so far:

```r
c("arg1", "arg2") %>% 
  map(parse_expr) %>% 
  exprs(!!!arg_names_chr, .named = TRUE)
#> $arg1
#> arg1
#> 
#> $arg2
#> arg2
#> 
#> # the contents of the list should be empty though...
```

I suppose using unquote-splice (`!!!`) is crucial keep the inputlength flexible, but I couldn't put it together with the empty lists needed for the `args`-part of `new_function` yet...

Comment: By the way don't create symbols with `base::parse()` or `rlang::parse_expr()`. Prefer `base::as.symbol()` or `rlang::sym()` which are much more robust. They always create a symbol whereas parsing might fail in all sorts of ways if there are special characters in the names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a list the usual way with `missing_arg()` in it:

```
arg_names <- c("arg1", "arg2")

args <- rep(list(missing_arg()), length(arg_names))
names(args) <- arg_names

new_function(args, NULL)
#> function (arg1, arg2)
#> NULL
```

Comment: Other ways of creating the missing arg: `base::quote(expr = )`, `rlang::expr()`, ...